# How can I write an Access (or Excel) query For range of values in one column change value of fields in another column

Tags: excel, ms-access

How can I write an Access (or Excel) query for a range of values in one column to change value of the respective fields in another column.

Of a range or array of values in column 'nParentSectionID' change value of respective fields in 'bSuppressHtml' to 'TRUE'

This would be the array follows:

`1, 10, 20, 22, 23, 37, 68, 97, 101, 103, 106, 115, 116, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 127, 129, 130, 131, 133, 136, 137, 141, 148, 157, 159, 160, 165, 166, 169, 170, 172, 174, 175, 176, 178, 180, 182, 184, 186, 187, 188, 190, 191, 193, 198, 200, 201, 202, 226, 229, 230, 231, 238, 241, 244, 247, 249, 252, 256, 259, 262, 263, 264, 266, 268, 270, 271, 277, 278, 280, 281, 282, 284, 286, 292, 296, 299, 307, 310, 319, 325, 329, 331, 335, 340, 341, 346, 348, 353, 362, 365, 366, 370, 374, 382, 383, 385, 386, 410, 412, 413, 416, 418, 419, 428, 429, 444, 446, 448, 451, 453, 456, 462, 463, 467, 469, 493, 500, 501, 502, 503, 505, 506, 511, 512, 515, 519, 525, 526, 527, 532, 535, 536, 537, 550, 551, 555, 563, 565, 566, 567, 573, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 581, 595, 598, 599, 603, 609, 611, 623, 626, 627, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 647, 651, 654, 655, 664, 669, 670, 672, 688, 689, 690, 695, 696, 697, 702, 705, 706, 716, 717, 725, 729, 731, 732, 738, 740, 741, 743, 744, 746, 749, 751, 752, 753, 757, 758, 759, 768, 772, 779, 782, 783, 802, 805, 810, 811, 814, 818, 819, 821, 836, 841, 846, 847, 849, 852, 854, 857, 862, 871, 872, 877, 882, 920, 922, 923, 930, 934, 935, 937, 938, 942, 944, 952, 958, 963, 981, 984, 987, 988, 991, 994, 1037, 1041, 1051, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1062, 1064, 1067, 1071, 1075, 1095, 1117, 1119, 1133, 1140, 1164, 1166, 1182, 1203, 1211, 1226, 1234, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1244, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1272, 1281, 1283, 1310, 1321, 1322, 1335, 1342, 1346, 1348, 1350, 1353, 1355, 1365, 1373, 1384, 1390, 1392, 1394, 1405, 1413, 1414, 1415, 1417, 1424, 1425, 1430, 1464, 1465, 1468, 1471, 1476, 1482, 1484, 1528, 1532, 1534, 1540, 1560, 1565, 1568, 1569, 1571, 1573, 1576, 1577, 1602, 1603, 1605, 1685, 1714, 1756, 1764, 1776, 1782, 1783, 1786, 1834, 1865, 1974, 1980, 1981, 1983, 1994, 1997, 2023, 2078, 2081, 2087, 2099, 2104, 2116, 2119, 2121, 2125, 2127, 2130, 2135, 2139, 2142, 2146, 2155, 2156, 2191, 2207, 2220, 2227, 2236, 2288, 2329, 2330, 2337, 2363, 2366, 2368, 2371, 2379, 2395, 2422, 2440, 2510, 2550, 2596, 2664, 2716, 2727, 2733, 2772, 2782, 2832, 2874, 2889, 2895, 2945, 2951, 3010, 3050, 3148, 3168, 3169, 3170, 3187, 3254, 3261, 3264, 3278, 3282, 3286, 3292, 3408, 3417, 3427, 3428, 3433, 3479, 3487, 3576, 3588, 3592, 3598, 3600, 3605, 3640, 3656, 3660, 3668, 3669, 3673, 3682, 3691`

Comment: Please understand, that SO is not a code writing but a code _helping_ forum. Better fora for this task might be _UtterAccess_ or _Experts Exchange_.

Comment: Thank you Gustav, I only know SO I am afraid and didn't want to clutter the post with my many failed attempts.

Comment: What do you mean by 'array'? Is this data all in one field or is each value in a separate record/row? What are the 'respective fields in another column'? Nothing in this question makes sense.

Comment: In general, readers prefer question authors to state their prior attempts - it gives them some context to explain where the code went wrong. It also shows that the author has made a good-faith attempt before asking readers for the solution.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't want to clutter the post with my many failed attempts. I have worked it out now, see below.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE product SET bSuppresshtml = true, bExcludeFromFroogle = true
WHERE nParentSectionID in (select nSectionID from [catalog section] where nSectionID in 
(1, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 22, 23, 37, 54, 68, 97, 101, 103, 106, 115, 116, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 127, 129, 130, 131, 133, 135, 136, 137, 141, 148, 157, 159, 160, 165, 166, 168, 169, 170, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 178, 180, 181, 182, 184, 186, 187, 188, 190, 191, 193, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 226, 229, 230, 231, 238, 241, 244, 246, 247, 249, 252, 256, 259, 262, 263, 264, 266, 268, 270, 271, 272, 277, 278, 280, 281, 282, 284, 286, 289, 290, 291, 292, 296, 299, 307, 310, 319, 323, 325, 329, 331, 335, 338, 339, 340, 341, 344, 346, 347, 348, 353, 362, 365, 366, 368, 370, 374, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 410, 411, 412, 413, 416, 418, 419, 425, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 444, 446, 448, 451, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 462, 463, 467, 469, 493, 496, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 555, 560, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 586, 592, 594, 595, 597, 598, 599, 600, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 609, 610, 611, 614, 617, 618, 623, 626, 627, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 654, 655, 656, 658, 660, 661, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 688, 689, 690, 695, 696, 697, 699, 702, 704, 705, 706, 716, 717, 725, 729, 731, 732, 737, 738, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 746, 748, 749, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 757, 758, 759, 768, 769, 770, 772, 776, 777, 778, 779, 781, 782, 783, 784, 787, 789, 802, 805, 810, 811, 812, 814, 818, 819, 820, 821, 836, 841, 843, 846, 847, 849, 850, 852, 853, 854, 856, 857, 861, 862, 865, 871, 872, 877, 882, 891, 892, 896, 897, 899, 903, 904, 908, 909, 910, 911, 916, 917, 918, 920, 922, 923, 924, 925, 927, 929, 930, 931, 934, 935, 937, 938, 942, 944, 948, 949, 950, 952, 958, 963, 980, 981, 984, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 1037, 1041, 1051, 1053, 1054, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1087, 1095, 1104, 1105, 1110, 1117, 1119, 1133, 1139, 1140, 1147, 1148, 1149, 1163, 1164, 1166, 1182, 1185, 1203, 1211, 1226, 1229, 1231, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243, 1244, 1245, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1265, 1269, 1272, 1281, 1283, 1310, 1318, 1321, 1322, 1335, 1342, 1346, 1348, 1350, 1352, 1353, 1355, 1362, 1365, 1373, 1384, 1386, 1387, 1390, 1392, 1393, 1394, 1395, 1396, 1397, 1405, 1411, 1412, 1413, 1414, 1415, 1416, 1417, 1423, 1424, 1425, 1430, 1431, 1432, 1433, 1434, 1435, 1436, 1437, 1438, 1439, 1464, 1465, 1466, 1468, 1471, 1476, 1482, 1484, 1487, 1489, 1495, 1496, 1497, 1498, 1503, 1504, 1506, 1518, 1528, 1532, 1534, 1540, 1560, 1561, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1568, 1569, 1570, 1571, 1572, 1573, 1576, 1577, 1580, 1585, 1591, 1592, 1593, 1596, 1600, 1602, 1603, 1605, 1633, 1645, 1671, 1681, 1682, 1683, 1685, 1714, 1723, 1724, 1725, 1726, 1727, 1756, 1764, 1773, 1776, 1777, 1778, 1779, 1780, 1781, 1782, 1783, 1784, 1785, 1786, 1788, 1789, 1791, 1803, 1804, 1805, 1806, 1807, 1808, 1809, 1810, 1812, 1813, 1814, 1816, 1834, 1835, 1865, 1937, 1974, 1980, 1981, 1983, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 2023, 2078, 2081, 2082, 2087, 2099, 2104, 2109, 2111, 2116, 2119, 2121, 2125, 2127, 2130, 2135, 2139, 2142, 2143, 2144, 2146, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2164, 2168, 2169, 2171, 2172, 2173, 2174, 2175, 2176, 2177, 2181, 2182, 2183, 2184, 2186, 2187, 2191, 2195, 2197, 2198, 2200, 2201, 2205, 2206, 2207, 2212, 2220, 2225, 2227, 2228, 2229, 2230, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2236, 2252, 2255, 2256, 2288, 2291, 2292, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2322, 2326, 2329, 2330, 2334, 2335, 2337, 2363, 2366, 2368, 2371, 2376, 2379, 2390, 2395, 2402, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2420, 2422, 2426, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2433, 2435, 2436, 2437, 2438, 2440, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2447, 2449, 2456, 2457, 2461, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2479, 2481, 2482, 2489, 2500, 2510, 2513, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2524, 2527, 2531, 2543, 2550, 2555, 2560, 2562, 2563, 2565, 2569, 2570, 2571, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2588, 2589, 2590, 2596, 2599, 2606, 2607, 2640, 2642, 2643, 2644, 2653, 2658, 2659, 2660, 2661, 2662, 2663, 2664, 2671, 2680, 2696, 2700, 2706, 2716, 2718, 2719, 2721, 2727, 2729, 2730, 2731, 2733, 2747, 2752, 2753, 2762, 2772, 2782, 2790, 2791, 2792, 2817, 2818, 2820, 2824, 2832, 2838, 2839, 2841, 2844, 2849, 2856, 2857, 2862, 2864, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2881, 2882, 2883, 2884, 2889, 2895, 2927, 2928, 2929, 2931, 2945, 2947, 2951, 2953, 2954, 2955, 2956, 2961, 2962, 2975, 2983, 2990, 3000, 3001, 3002, 3005, 3010, 3014, 3019, 3020, 3021, 3035, 3050, 3056, 3058, 3064, 3065, 3066, 3067, 3068, 3070, 3072, 3073, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3082, 3091, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3128, 3148, 3167, 3168, 3169, 3170, 3181, 3183, 3187, 3200, 3202, 3215, 3224, 3225, 3253, 3254, 3255, 3256, 3258, 3259, 3260, 3261, 3262, 3263, 3264, 3267, 3271, 3272, 3274, 3278, 3279, 3282, 3286, 3292, 3300, 3309, 3319, 3320, 3321, 3325, 3326, 3328, 3345, 3349, 3358, 3359, 3367, 3368, 3369, 3374, 3396, 3405, 3408, 3417, 3422, 3423, 3427, 3428, 3431, 3433, 3446, 3473, 3474, 3475, 3476, 3477, 3478, 3479, 3487, 3495, 3496, 3499, 3500, 3503, 3515, 3531, 3533, 3534, 3565, 3576, 3588, 3592, 3598, 3600, 3605, 3640, 3656, 3660, 3668, 3669, 3673, 3682, 3691, )
);
```

Grateful to you for looking, the above works perfectly.